# Paying the bills proportionally to the time we stay in the flat.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm sharing a flat with other 3 people.

The bills have just arrived and now we have to pay them proportionally to the time we stay in the flat.

If I arrived in the middle of the month, and the others have stayed the hole month, how much have to pay each person?

Answer (score 4):

Your times of stay are in proportion to $\frac12$, $1$, $1$ and $1$; the sum of these weights is $\frac72$, so you should pay

$$\frac{\frac12}{\frac72}=\frac17\;,\\
\frac{1}{\frac72}=\frac27\;,\\
\frac{1}{\frac72}=\frac27\;,\\
\frac{1}{\frac72}=\frac27\;,\\
$$

respectively.

Comment: Thanks! well we are in four so I think have to change 5 by 7.

Comment: @tirengarfio: Ah, sorry, yes, I just read "3 people"; I'll correct it.